# Alternative to COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) for retrieving millions of data

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

I have a table that store more than 10 million of data and when I use simple query such as

```
SELECT TOP 10 COALESCE(a.Name, 'NA') AS Name, 
              COUNT(DISTINCT a.Id) AS Result1, 
              COUNT(b.Id) AS Result2 
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Id = b.Id 
GROUP BY a.Name
```

it takes approximately 20 mins to return the result.

Is there any way to count the distinct column faster than using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?

*I also tried to use `GROUP BY` but its just the same.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What is the `CREATE TABLE`? What indexes are on the table? How many distinct values are actually in the table?

Comment: Is your table INDEXED on `column_name`?

Comment: I just ran similar queries on a varchar column (un-indexed, as far as I can tell) in a table with 15 million rows, and got execution times in the region of 80 seconds, which seems reasonable to me. I don't think there's anything wrong with the queries. Indexing may be the answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'm using SQL and it indexed the primary key. I'm retrieving the column(foreign key) and it has to unique.

Comment: why not select count of the ids in the foreign key table where the id is in the large table?

Comment: @gynnel Could you please tell us which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. PFB:
`SELECT TOP 10 COALESCE(a.Name, 'NA') AS Name, COUNT(DISTINCT a.Id) AS Result1, COUNT(b.Id) AS Result2
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Id = b.Id
GROUP BY a.Name`.
This is the exact query that I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the column is a foreign key column you might can try to select the count from the foreign key table where the ID exists in the larger table.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) 
FROM   SmallTable
WHERE  Id IN (Select foreignKeyID from LargeTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
select count(column_name) as n
from (select distinct column_name from yourTable) as a
```

This way, the heavy-weight task of deduplication is done by a simple `SELECT`.

I'm of course assuming that your column is indexed. If it's not, I strongly suggest you add an index to it.

Comment: I would be very surprised if any modern DBMS would execute that differently than the original query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I wouldn't be surprised if the execution plans were different.  I also think that MySQL might be more inclined to used an index for this version.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for SQL Server the plans are identical. I think MySQL is about the only database that is low-featured enough not to optimize this to the fullest.

Comment: @usr . . . Optimizing for a single `count(distinct)` is quite an ad-hoc optimization.  This answer is correct for Hive (I knew I had seen this recently). Including any other columns in the `select` changes the optimization strategy (basically, whether the distinct is done *after* aggregation partitioning or as part of the aggregation partitioning).  Such one-off optimizations are not a priority for optimizers.

Comment: SQL Server has many very general rewrites that come together to build great plans. Almost all queries are kind of one off.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable database should take advantage an index on `table(column_name)` for your query.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your RDBMS it's impossible to say for sure, but most likely no, there is not a better way.  I would guess that you need an index on that column, and that adding one would reduce the query time down to seconds.